# Не могу запустить сервер php

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

Подскажите, как правильно запустить сервер с уже готовым api на windows. В инструкции сказано просто открыть терминал в нужной директории и прописать "sh setup.sh". Но это, конечно же, не сработает. Я так понимаю, нужно установить php, laravel, composer, sqlite... Но даже после получаются ошибки и к базе данных подключиться не получается... При установке в терминале ошибка такая "could not find driver PDOException". Заранее прошу прощения за тупость, с php ранее дела не имела.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: установить надо только РНР. остальное все устанавливает скрипт. просто скачать РНР, развернуть, добавить папку в PATH, переименовать php.ini и раскомментировать в нем sqlite

Comment: чтобы скрипт запускался, можно поставить себе git bash

Comment: @Ипатьев Вау! Работает, спасибо огромное! Всё оказалось так просто...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Установить php
2. Добавить папку в системные переменные
3. Раскомментировать строчки с sqlite в php.ini
4. Запустить скрипт через git bash